# Does a firmware update remain when changing the OS?

Tags: update, operating-systems, firmware, rpi-update

If I do a firmware update via `sudo rpi-update` on Raspbian Buster on the Pi 4 and then flash another OS (e.g. LibreELEC) to the SD card, will the firmware still be up-to-date?

Comment: are you referring to the pi-4 eeprom bootloader?

Comment: If using `rp-update` the firmware is never up to date. It is noted that it may be unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rpi-update` command updates the **kernel**. The SD card's boot partition holds the kernel. So if you re-flash your SD card, the kernel will be replaced.

If you meant to say `rpi-eeprom-update` though, that is different. This command updates the RPi's internal EEPROM storage, and it will not be reset if you re-flash the SD card.

BTW **you should never have to run either of those commands**. Countless beginners have bricked their SD Cards with an unbootable experimental kernel, and the EEPROM is kept updated automatically via APT.

Comment: I though about updating the firmware because of the heat which the cpu produces. I've heard the firmware update cools the cpu a bit down.

Comment: Yes, past firmware updates have made the Pi4s run cooler. But again, APT should be updating that by default, and there's a systemd service called `Check for Raspberry Pi EEPROM updates` that runs on boot.

Answer (score 1):

No, "flashing" an SD cards destroys all data including the "boot" partition, which in turn includes the firmware files. The firmware will be reset to the version which is included in the LibreELEC image.